# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier

Tags: android-espresso, androidx, ui-testing, wiremock

Android Studio 3.3

I want to use **WireMock** in my **Espresso** tests.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.KOTLIN_VERSION = '1.3.21'
    ext.ESPRESSO_VERSION = '3.2.0-alpha02'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$KOTLIN_VERSION"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
// Need to autocreate tasks crashlyticsUploadDistributionXXX
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("app/keystore.properties")))

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.android"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.0.8"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
        //androidTest.assets.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/assets'
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.yuyh.json:jsonviewer:1.0.6'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$KOTLIN_VERSION"

    implementation project(':common')

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'

    androidTestImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.18.0")

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here Espresso's test:

```
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.intent.rule.IntentsTestRule
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.*
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AddTraderActivityTest {
    val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext()
    val targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()

    @get:Rule
    var addTraderIntentTestRule: IntentsTestRule<AddTraderActivity> = IntentsTestRule(AddTraderActivity::class.java)

    @get:Rule
    var wireMockRule = WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(8081))

 @Test
 fun toolbar_title() {
    onView(withId(R.id.toolbaTitleTextView))
            .check(matches(withText(R.string.traders)))
  }
```

But I get error in this line:

```
var wireMockRule = WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(8081))

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:958)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.HttpClientFactory.createClient(HttpClientFactory.java:76)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.ProxyResponseRenderer.<init>(ProxyResponseRenderer.java:58)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.buildStubRequestHandler(WireMockApp.java:131)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:73)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule.<init>(WireMockRule.java:43)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule.<init>(WireMockRule.java:39)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:389)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this comes way later than your question but I wanted to post what I found while running into this same issue incase others come across it.

In order to avoid this specific problem I had to change the dependency reference within Gradle to the standalone variant of Wiremock

from:

`androidTestImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.18.0")`

to:

`androidTestImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.18.0")`

I preserved the original poster's version of 2.18.0 for consistency, however, I ran into this issue using version 2.26.0.

I am not certain as to why the standlone version of the dependency resolves the issue but I suspect it has to do with another dependency causing some sort of underlying conflict.